# Get File Name which is currently writing in WriteFile

Tags: c++, winapi

```
BOOL WINAPI MyWriteFile(
 _In_        HANDLE       hFile,
 _In_        LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
 _In_        DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
 _Out_opt_   LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
 _Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
)
{
LPTSTR filepath;
DWORD  filepathlength=500;    
GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile,filepath,filepathlength,FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
return WriteFile(hFile,lpBuffer,nNumberOfBytesToWrite,lpNumberOfBytesWritten,lpOverlaped)
}
```

This function is written in dll which is implementing security of software in which this is injected i want to get file name which is currently writing. I tried to use GetFinalPathNameByHandle() but in Visual studio 2013 it says GetFinalPathNameByHandle is undefined. Any help in this regard will appreciated.

Edited

Error List

Error   2

error C3861: 'GetFinalPathNameByHandle': identifier not found   test.cpp    132     test.cpp

IntelliSense: identifier "GetFinalPathNameByHandle" is undefined test.cpp   132     test.cpp

Edit 2

```
i included #include <FileAPI.h> 

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <assert.h>
#include <FileAPI.h>
```

But i am still getting same errors.

Edit 3

Problem Solved by removing these lines from stdafx.h

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP 
or 
later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to 
target other versions of Windows.
#endif
```

Thank you All

Comment: Well it's *good* that you can't build it, because if you did then you would have *undefined behavior*. According to [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962(v=vs.85).aspx) the second argument is an output argument, it must point to an allocated buffer. And you don't provide such a buffer. Instead you provide an uninitialized pointer variable. You should instead have an array of `TCHAR`, at least `filepathlength + 1` elements large.

Comment: As for helping you with your problem, can you please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output and include it in the question? *As text.*

Comment: Thank you. i corrected error and allocated TCHAR buffer. i edited question and errors listed please check that.

Comment: This is why we need a [mcve].  The problem is that your code has not declared `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`.  According to MSDN, it is included in FileAPI.h, which is included in Windows.h.  *However*, my guess is that you have defined `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` (probably in stdafx.h) before including Windows.h, and this has suppressed FileAPI.h.  Either remove the LEAN_AND_MEAN, or explicitly include FileAPI.h.

Comment: If the above actually solves the problem, I'll make it an answer, but at the moment I am just guessing.

Comment: [mcve] please ....

Comment: must be `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600` possible you not define it. anyway your code absolute wrong

Comment: Thank you Sir i already figured out problem here is                                           #ifndef _WIN32_WINNT  // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif   i removed this these lines from stdafx.h which were causing poblem. more ever you can make you comment as answer

Comment: Note that `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` requires a file handle for a file or directory in a file system that's mounted on a volume. It will fail if the handle is for a device such as C: (volume), PhysicalDrive0 (disk), NUL, PIPE, CON or CONOUT$. You could fill in some of the gaps using combination of system calls, but not all of them -- not without loading a device driver. For example, for console handles in 8+ `NtQueryObject` will give you `\Device\ConDrv`, but this device doesn't implement querying `FileNameInformation` to retrieve the opened virtual file (e.g. Connect, Output, CurrentOut).

Comment: I've had the unfortunate experience of trying to deal with such a "security DLL" before, written by someone equally unqualified. This type of DLL causes crashes in other applications, and can lead Windows users to just reformat their PC. Luckily, anti-virus software now tends to signal such injected DLLs as malware and forcefully terminate the offender.

Comment: Dear MSalters 2 this dll has nothing to do with any other applications. This dll created for specific application and version. Whole project is completed and tested and it is working very well. Thank you for your concern.